# How to Add Combobox in datagridview only for header?

Tags: vb.net

This is my code - I want to add `combobox` for my second column. So that whatever value user enter in that column I can use for further operation. I have changed Items in combo intentionally.

```
Dim cmbHeaderCell As New ComboBox
cmbHeaderCell1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
cmbHeaderCell1.Visible = True

cmbHeaderCell1.Items.Add("India")
cmbHeaderCell1.Items.Add("China")
DGrdVLoadStb.Columns(1).Width = cmbHeaderCell1.Width

cmbHeaderCell1.Location = DGrdVLoadStb.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, -1,True).Location
cmbHeaderCell1.Size = DGrdVLoadStb.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Size
cmbHeaderCell1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Here I am getting the location `(0, 0)` from `GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, -1, True)` method. I have checked many related questions on stackOverflow but I didn't get perfect answer please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To which surface do you add your combo box? Is it floating on the form?

Comment: Right now ? Yes it is on top left corner of datagridview. I want it at header of second column.

Comment: I guess, your problem is that when you getting X,Y from the grid, it is relative to the grid. So, you need to create offset logic to the surface on which grid sits. So, lets say, `grid.control.Location` returns `0,0` , on form it may be `10,20`

Comment: Thanks. Actually I managed to solve the problem by using width of first column as X for location of combo and Y as 2. I know it's not perfect answer but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in comment, I managed to do this by using,
1. width of first column of `datagridview` adding 2 to it and 
2. making it as X of my `combobox` loacation and Y as 2. 
here is my code,

```
        Dim cmbHeaderCell1 As New ComboBox
        cmbHeaderCell1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        cmbHeaderCell1.Visible = True
        cmbHeaderCell1.Items.Clear()
        cmbHeaderCell1.Items.Add("India")
        cmbHeaderCell1.Items.Add("China")
        DGrdVLoadStb.Columns(1).Width = cmbHeaderCell1.Width

        'Dim X As Integer = DGrdVLoadStb.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, -1, False).Location.X
        'Dim Y As Integer = DGrdVLoadStb.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, -1, True).Location.Y
        cmbHeaderCell1.Location = New Point(datagridview1.Columns(0).Width + 2, 2)
        cmbHeaderCell1.Size = DGrdVLoadStb.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Size
        cmbHeaderCellStressRate.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        DGrdVLoadStb.Controls.Add(cmbHeaderCell1)
        cmbHeaderCell1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

If any one have better solution please post it I will accept it.