# Add comboBox in column header

Tags: vb.net, windows

Hi im using vb to create my application and i want to add combobox to column header like the image below

[image]

Comment: @Jinx88909 not yet i dont know how to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a duplicate question. See [How to Add Combobox in datagridview only for header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208596/how-to-add-combobox-in-datagridview-only-for-header)

But also this link has some nice example code, which I've copied below. 
[MSDN: Dropdown/ComboBox Column Header Cell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/69eb64a8-fa93-4f99-b48e-5666287edc3b/dropdowncombobox-column-header-cell?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                // Create a ComboBox which will be host in column1's cell
                ComboBox comboBoxHeaderCell1 = new ComboBox();
                comboBoxHeaderCell1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                comboBoxHeaderCell1.Visible = true;
                comboBoxHeaderCell1.Items.Add("Column1");
                comboBoxHeaderCell1.Items.Add("Column2");

                // Add the ComboBox to the header cell of column1
                dataGridView1.Controls.Add(comboBoxHeaderCell1);            
                comboBoxHeaderCell1.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Location;
                comboBoxHeaderCell1.Size = this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Size;
                comboBoxHeaderCell1.Text = "Column1";
        }
    }
```